# multiplying 3 variable a ,bi, cj

Tags: complex-numbers

I know how to do this
$A × B  =  ( a + bi ) × ( c + di )$, 
but I don't understand how to do this 
$ A × B  =( a + bi +cj) × ( d + ei +fj) =? $
I'm not sure how to group them or what to do with the i and the j as in this  $+cj × ei$
 Its for a fractal program im writing

Comment: Are you *multiplying* (evidently quaternions), or taking the *cross product* of vectors? I suspect the latter, but ... it's hard to say exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: i am not very well versed in math

Comment: You would need to define what $j^2$ or $ij$ or $ji$ would be in the case of your mulitplication.  Hamilton wanted this case before he came up with Quaternions....

Comment: @google That's fine, but if you can't even say what objects you're trying to manipulate, anyone hoping to answer has to basically grasp at straws (and that's not even touching on what you could possibly do with an answer whose underlying context you don't understand).

Comment: i only have 3 variable to work with could i just make the 4th variable zero in the quaternions  equation to make it work?

Comment: Note this is not a closed system if you work in the Quaternions since $ij=k$ and $ji=-k$...

Comment: yes  i know that

Answer (score 0):

Just distribute...
$$(a+bi+cj)(d+ei+fj)=$$
$$(ad-be-cf)+(ae-bd)i+(af+cd)j+(bf-ce)k$$

We get the k terms since 
$$biej=beij=bek$$
And
$$cjei=ceji=-cek$$

Comment: thank very much i will try to work with this in my program